# Object created via read.csv disappears after script finishes

Tags: r, rstudio

I am not a programmer and have less than a month of experience with R but have been writing simple scripts that read from external CSV files for the past week.  The function below, which reads data from a CSV file, was originally more complex but I repeatedly shortened it during troubleshooting until I was left with this:

```
newfunction <- function(input1, input2) {
  processingobject <- read.csv("processing-file.csv")
  print(head(processingobject))
}
```

I can print both the head and the entire `processingobject` within the script without a problem, but after the script ends processingobject no longer exists. It never appears in the RStudio global environment pane.  Shouldn't `processingobject` still exist after the script terminates?

The script runs without displaying any error or warning messages. I tried assigning `processingobject` to a second variable: `processingobject2 <- processingobject` but the second variable doesn't exist after the script ends either. I also tried clearing the global environment and restarting RStudio, but that did not work either. If at the prompt after the script I type `processingobject` I get the message `"Error: object 'processingobject' not found"`. The CSV file itself is perfectly normal as far as I can tell.

Obviously, I must be doing something very stupid. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: That's right: `processingobject` no longer exists. It was a local object and after exit from the function, it will be garbage collected. The only objects whose values will persist are ones that were assigned to a name in the global environment via one of three mechanisms: 1) assignment of the last evaluation to a token in the global environment as is demonstrated for newcsv token in the answer below, 2) assignment to a token with `<<-`, or 3) assignment with `assign` using an argument to the 'env' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `return` in your function and reproducible examples are always a good idea. It makes it easier for people to help you out.

```
ncol<- 10
nrow<- 100
x <- matrix(runif(nrow*ncol),nrow,ncol)
write.csv(x,file="example_data.csv")

newfunction <- function(input1) {
  processingobject <- read.csv("example_data.csv")
  result <- apply(processingobject,2,function(x)x*input1) #doing something to csv with input
  print(head(result))
  return(result)
}

newcsv <-newfunction(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is still present after adding the extra 'return(result)' line. The only change is that now after I run the function it returns NULL but the object is still not found. How can I make my example more reproducible - do I need to include the actual CSV file or some other information?

Comment: Have a look at this post: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and edit your post so we can see what is happening. You might have an issue with reading in the csv?